# Creating two divs with equal size, but different font-size, in ems

Tags: css, font-size

I've been reading into ems a lot, and I see why we should use them.

So now I'm trying to apply it to my layout. In my layout I've got two `div` next to each other. The left one has got a `font-size: 1em;` and the second one has got a `font-size: 0.8em`.

Both `div` should have equal size and margin. (in this example they are 6em width, 1em margin)

Now the problem I bump into:
The first `div`, with `font-size: 1em`, is (by browser default of 16px) `16 x 1 x 6 = 96px`
The second `div`, with `font-size: .8em`, is `16 x .8 x 6 = 76.8px`

See this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9LPF/), as a demonstration.

In order to make both div equal of size, but with different font-sizes in need this code:

```
body {
    font-size: 1em;
}
div { 
    margin: 1em; 
    background: lightgreen;
    float: left;
}
.blue {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    clear: left;
    background: lightblue;
}
.small2 {
    font-size: .8em;
    width: 7.5em;    
    height: 7.5em; 
    margin: 1.25em;
}
```

Which means I have to override the general style I declared at `div` with the style for `.small2`.

Is this the way to go, or am I overlooking a better solution?

Comment: Or if you want the two boxes to be equal size **independent of font size** then use `px`.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of defining div width using em is. It seem like you are over complicating things

Comment: @Huangism: you might be right. *But*, I read all about web-accessibility and how you *should* use ems, because the are scalable for the user. With that in mind I figured that if I set my div to an em width, the layout will always have the same look. But I also read that modern browsers can scale px units too, is there than any advantage of using ems instead of px?

Comment: I think it will be harder to maintain. Imagine changing the size of anything later on, a lot of calculations is needed for a small change.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I bumped in to... But having browser scaling px aswell as em, doesn't that make ems obsolete?

Comment: What is wrong with the 7.5em/1.25em approach?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but this is easier. Consider that you want a font-size of .834em (for some vague reason). I would need a calculator to determine the height of the div. By setting the font-size to the children, I don't....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works good for me. I leave the font-size on the parent unchanged, instead I change the font-size of the children.

HTML:

```
<div class="blue"><p>blue</p></div>
<div class="small"><p>test</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.normal {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
}
.small {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
}
.small p {
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9LPF/2/) (the two divs in the middle).

Answer (score 3):

Try using `rem`s - they have the same advantage as ems but are relative to the font-size of the `<body>` tag rather than the containing element.

so:

```
.blue {
    width: [target size, in pixels]
    width: 6rem;
    height: [target size, in pixels]
    height: 6rem;
    clear: left;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Note that rems are not supported in all browsers (IE8 and earlier) so you should employ a pixel fallback (as above) when using them.

Comment: Sweet solution, too bad it isn't crossbrowser. Also see the comment on my OP... Is there any use of ems with browser that also scale px?

Comment: With the fallback (which causes the flexibility to be lost), is this really simpler than just calculating the values that you use as multipliers of `em`?

Comment: Another solution would be to not apply any font-size to the .box and instead add another container within that box and apply the font-size to that.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela no it isn't, but in the long run (as Huangism mentioned) this might be more flexible than doing em math if dimensions or font-sizes have to change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s the way, but you should think simply and forget about pixels (which have no defined relation to the `em` unit and would just confuse here). If you save `0.8em` font size for some element and you want its dimensions equal the dimensions with another element (which inherits its font size from `body`), simply multiply values by the inverse of 0.8, i.e. 1.25.

Comment: Yes, I know I shouldn't think in px any more. But it helps me to estimate the size I want. This way doesn't make it easier, IMO.